# How to apply filters on spark scala dataframe view?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, apache-spark-sql, view

I am pasting a snippet here where I am facing issues with the BigQuery Read. The "wherePart" has more number of records and hence BQ call is invoked again and again. Keeping the filter outside of BQ Read would help. The idea is, first read the "mainTable" from BQ, store it in a spark view, then apply the "wherePart" filter to this view in spark.
[***"subDate" is a function to subtract one date from another and return the number of days in between***]

```
  val Df =  getFb(config, mainTable, ds)

  def getFb(config: DataFrame, mainTable: String, ds: String) : DataFrame = {

    val fb = config.map(row => Target.Pfb(
      row.getAs[String]("m1"),
      row.getAs[String]("m2"),
      row.getAs[Seq[Int]]("days")))
      .collect

    val wherePart = fb.map(x => (x.m1, x.m2, subDate(ds, x.days.max - 1))).
      map(x => s"(idata_${x._1} = '${x._2}' AND ds BETWEEN '${x._3}' AND '${ds}')").
      mkString(" OR ")

    val q = new Q()
    val tempView = "tempView"
    spark.readBigQueryTable(mainTable, wherePart).createOrReplaceTempView(tempView)
    val Df = q.mainTableLogs(tempView)
    Df
  }
```

Could someone please help me here.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the [spark-bigquery-connector](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/spark-bigquery-connector)? If so the right syntax is

```
spark.read.format("bigquery")
  .load(mainTable)
  .where(wherePart)
  .createOrReplaceTempView(tempView)
```